# "with a combination" or "by a combination"?

Tags: word-usage

We have the following statement: "The final 3D effect is realized by a combination of the native 3D effect and a shadow effect". Is it all right to say "realized by ..." or should it be "realized with ..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Maciej's answer is correct but it is stated rather specifically: the abstract principle is embedded in a concrete example. Here is the abstract principle:

Since **by** denotes *instrumentality*, it partners semantically with an action, here **combining**:

> The final 3D effect is realized **by combining** the native 3D effect and
>   a shadow effect.

Paraphrase: The native 3D effect and a shadow effect *are combined in order to produce* the final 3D effect.

Since **with** denotes *participation* or *involvement* or *agency*, it partners semantically with a noun that participates in or is involved in  or is a co-agent in an action:

> The final 3D effect is realized  **with a combination** of the native 3D effect and a shadow effect.

Paraphrase: The final 3D effect is a result of using *the native 3D effect and a shadow effect*.

P.S.
To complicate matters, the abstract ideas of *instrumentality* and *participation/involvement/agency* can shade into one another. The complement of **with** can be an instrument, co-actor, or co-agency:

> I chopped the tree down with this axe, said George.
>
> We did it with their help.
>
> The dentist repaired the tooth with his dental assistant.

But we would not say **realized with combining**.

And sometimes the underlying verb of nouns like **combination** will cause speakers to use **by** with the noun:

> The final 3D effect is realized **by a combination** of the native 3D effect and a shadow effect.

That last sentence strikes my ear as somewhat "off" because the action of combining is not immediate but one step removed.  There is a forced "cast":

```
         by (verb) noun
```

Answer (score 7):

If the effect is realized **with** a tool, it means that someone or something is utilizing the tool to create the effect, while if the effect is realized **by** a tool, it means that the tool is creating the effect itself.

In the context you mention, I'd say they're more or less interchangeable - I'd lean towards "realized with" when focusing on an artist or game developer applying the effects to create the final product, and "realized by" when focusing more on the product itself.